# Toasting sandwich bread before packing a lunch - when is it appropriate?

Tags: bread, sandwich

When I make a sandwich to eat fresh, I pretty much always toast the bread. When I pack a sandwich to eat later, however, I don't. I've always thought that eating cold toast would be gross. Recently though I'm starting to rethink this position. What would happen if I toasted bread, made a sandwich, and then ate it hours later?

If I did this, does it work better for certain kinds of bread, or certain sandwich fillings? Does it matter if the sandwich is stored in a chilled cooler, or in a room-temperature brown bag? In short, **is it ever a good idea to toast a sandwich that won't be eaten until hours later, and if so, when?**

Comment: This question made me laugh.. +1

Answer (score 10):

I usually toast most of my sandwiches (or the grilled cheese kind) for hikes and picnics. My general rules are: no filling that releases water (fresh tomato, for example) and wrap in paper (tissue or napkin) and then plastic or foil (or a cooler/plastic container). Keep in the fridge until needed or when packing your bag. The paper will prevent most of the moisture from condensation making your bread mushy. It won't have the crispness of fresh made toast, but it's pretty good.

Answer (score 9):

I agree with everything Reven said. One additional note, though: make sure that the toast is completely cooled before wrapping the sandwich up. Otherwise the bread is still releasing steam, which could soften the bread.

Comment: Yes, missed that detail. Very true. :)

Comment: Also, if you use a spread such as mayonnaise or mustard, consider putting the spread between slices of the filling to avoid it making the bread soggy. (For example, put down a slice of cheese or meat and then the spread, then more filling.)

Answer (score 1):

Toast your sandwich then quickly place in freezer in foil only this will take any moisture out and give you the perfect sandwich